# Validação de email php erro

Tags: php, email, validação

Estou fazendo a validação do campo e-mail do meu form e na parte de validar a estrutura do e-mail preciso de uma ajuda.
Quando der  else, não quero que ele envie as informações para o banco de dados, quero que ele dê falso e mostre que o campo está inválido e não envie o form, e que o usuario tem de escrever um email válido, mas quando da else ele envia o form, como eu posso mudar isso ? Segue uma parte do meu código:

```
<?php            $email = array_key_exists('email', $_POST) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>
                <p><label></label></br> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/></p>
                <?php
        if($_POST)
         {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            if ($email == "") {
                echo '<p style="font-family: Microsoft JhengHei Light;color:#fff;"><strong style="color:#8E0303;">Aviso:</strong> Campo não preenchido!</p>';
            }}
    ?>
    <?php
        if($_POST)
         {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
            {
                echo '<p style="font-family: Microsoft JhengHei Light;color:#fff;"><strong style="color:#8E0303;">Aviso:</strong> Email válido</p>';
            }else{
            echo"invalido";}
        }
    ?>
```

Quero uma ajuda na parte do else, pra nao conseguir cadastrar o usuario enquanto nao estiver certo o campo...

Obs¹:Na parte do if, quando o usuario colocar o email certo e outro campo estiver incorreto, aparecerá a mensagem do email válido.
Obs²:Em cima do input há algo para quando o usuario colocar o email certo e outro campo qualquer estiver incorreto, não apagara o texto escrito no campo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem um erro de lógica no seu código. A parte final que começa depois do primeiro parágrafo (`<p></p>`, que contém o `<input...>`) poderia ser reescrita, sem prejuízo, da seguinte forma.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo '<p style="font-family: Microsoft JhengHei Light;color:#fff;"><strong style="color:#8E0303;">Aviso:</strong> Email válido</p>';
    } else {
        echo"invalido";
    }
} else {
    echo '<p style="font-family: Microsoft JhengHei Light;color:#fff;"><strong style="color:#8E0303;">Aviso:</strong> Campo não preenchido!</p>';
}
```

Comment: Boa resposta, só uma dica quando usa `empty` não precisa de `isset` ;), também pode-se usar `isset($_POST['email']{0})`, seria semelhante ao `empty`, mas para usar `{0}` é necessário php5.3+.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode validar o e-mail antes mesmo de enviar o form para o PHP usando o HTML.
Exemplo:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Insira seu email">
```